# Arduino ADK ways to connect to an Android tablet

Tags: android, usb, arduino, tablet, adk

Is it possible to connect [Arduino ADK](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardADK) and Android through a USB cable in two ways?

- The first way is through the same connector (USB1) as used at programming, and
- The second way is through a USB interface (USB2)?

So can I use one of these two ways?

Answer (score 0):

It will probably be easier to use the second USB. It acts like a USB host, and you will be able to use the ADK code. You can also use the USB port you use for programming, but if you use it, your Android phone/tablet must be the USB host.